# Is ActionListener a thread in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, actionlistener

Is action listener a thread, and if it is, what is the affect of this thread on my own-defined threads??

especially in Swing/AWT when you define your own thread, or when you use a thread to make an animation, is actionlistener affect that? and why?

Comment: in what context?  Swing/AWT?  Or just the ActionListener interface in general?

Comment: especially in Swing/AWT when you define your own thread, or when you use a thread to make an animation, is actionlistener affect that? and why?

Comment: @Mohamed Magdy Hassan nobody knows whats your goal, please don't comment, but edit your question,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, an action listener is an interface. You can implement that interface by defining what its `actionPerformed()` method does (assuming you refer to [this ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html)). That method is going to run in the thread that calls it.

So if you call it from one of your threads, it will run in that thread. If `actionPerformed` interacts with UI components, it is probably a bad idea to do that.

You can read more about [ActionListeners in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [Concurrency & Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

- have look at [Swing Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)
- `Swing Action` is most scalable in compare with [AWT Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html)
- output from `Swing Action` should be [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)
- output from `Swing Action` should be always in done [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

EDIT

> Mohamed Magdy Hassan wrote especially in Swing/AWT when you define your own thread, or when you use a thread to make an animation, is actionlistener affect that? and why?

- don't use thread (`Thread` or `Runnable#Thread`) for animations for `Swing JComponents`, this could be correct for `AWT` or partially for `SWT`,
- please forgot for examples from the interner, most of them are out - dated, for `Swing JComponents` use [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) exclusivelly